# How to use the #M dispatch function in the series package?

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to understand the basics of the `series` [library](https://www.cliki.net/Series) and am studying the examples in the [CL Cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/iteration.html#series-4)

But if I try to evaluate one of this examples

```
SERIES> (collect
          (#Mlist (scan '(a b c))
                  (scan '(1 2 3))))
```

I get the following error from `SBCL 2.03`:

```
no dispatch function defined for #\M

  Line: 2, Column: 15, File-Position: 23

  Stream: #<SB-IMPL::STRING-INPUT-STREAM {1004122F53}>
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-ERROR]
```

I loaded `series` using `quicklisp` and don't get where the dispatch function `#M` should be defined. Could someone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reader macros for libraries typically need to be enabled explicitly.

According to the RELEASE-NOTES:

> You can use SERIES::INSTALL for "use-package"ing Series in a way that
>   extended special forms are shadow-import'ed and reader macros are
>   installed.

I'm not sure why that is not exported.

I have not yet found a `named-readtables` definition for series, but I'd guess that someone has done that alredy.